# Target log not found in binlog index, from purge binary logs mysqld-relay-bin

Tags: mysql, binlog

I am trying to run the following.

```
mysql > purge binary logs to 'mysqld-relay-bin.000075';
ERROR 1373 (HY000): Target log not found in binlog index

# cat ./mysqld-relay-bin.index 
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000010
....
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000075
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000076
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000077
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000078
/srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.000079
```

What can I do to manually clear remove these relay logs.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show master status;
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File          | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| binary.000141 | 487953618 |              |                  |
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+


ls -lrt /var/lib/mysql/logs/
total 4616604
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        299 Jun  7 15:04 mysqld-relay-bin.000010
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        299 Jun  7 15:19 mysqld-relay-bin.000011
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        299 Jun  7 15:21 mysqld-relay-bin.000012
....
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        299 Jul 23 01:15 mysqld-relay-bin.000075
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        299 Jul 23 01:15 mysqld-relay-bin.000076
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        268 Jul 24 09:17 mysqld-relay-bin.000077
```

As part of a backup script that I run. 
I flush logs every night, could that have an effect.

Maser server where the replication logs are piling up.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';  
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 1000  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%relay%';
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                                  |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+
| max_relay_log_size    | 1073741824                             |
| relay_log             | /srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin       |
| relay_log_basename    | /srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin       |
| relay_log_index       | /srv/mysql/logs/mysqld-relay-bin.index |
| relay_log_info_file   | relay-log.info                         |
| relay_log_purge       | ON                                     |
| relay_log_recovery    | OFF                                    |
| relay_log_space_limit | 0                                      |
| sync_relay_log        | 10000                                  |
| sync_relay_log_info   | 10000                                  |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Slave that connects to the master.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 1002  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]>  SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.21.228.81
                  Master_User: db.replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: binary.000141
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 540479720
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000358
                Relay_Log_Pos: 540480005
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binary.000141
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 540479720
              Relay_Log_Space: 540480344
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1000
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: No query specified
```

Comment: The relay logs necessarily go away on their own. If valid logs are sticking around, please check few things.

First, Are the server_id values (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';) distinct across all connected Master(s) and Slave(s)? 

Seconds, SHOW SLAVE STATUS; -- is replication caught up? Check Seconds_behind_master, plus check SQL and I/O thread. If replication stopped, or is behind, the relay logs are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two things: "binlogs" and "relaylogs"

The Master writes to a sequence of binlogs on the Master.  These are purged by any of (*) expire_logs_days, (*) explicit PURGE, (*) OS delete command (not recommended, but possible).

The Slave receives data from the Master's binlogs and immediately writes the data to a sequence of "relay logs" that live on the Slave.  The "IO Thread" does that.  Meanwhile, the "SQL thread" is reading the relaylogs and performing the actions.  As it finishes a relaylog, it automatically deletes the file.  No manual action should ever be needed on the relay logs.

What you did was to try a *binlog* action on the *relaylogs*.  Don't do that.

*Normally*, there will be *one*, occasionally two, relay logs visible on the Slave.  Since you are seeing dozens, the Slave must be *terribly far behind* on replication.  This probably means that it is stuck.  Perform `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` to see why.  After fixing the problem, the relay logs will cleanup (as mentioned above).

If you do manage to remove/purge/whatever those relay logs, you will permanently break replication.  You will have to rebuild the Slave from scratch.  So, do *not* delete those files.  (Unless you are rebuilding the Slave, at which point they are ancient history.)

**But it is the Master??**

- Is it a "Dual-Master" setup?  That is when each of two servers is both Master and Slave to each other.
- Or it used to be a Slave, and these logs were not cleaned out?
- Hmmm... all the logs seem to be "empty" (299 bytes), as if something was mis-configured?  Such as...
- Dual-Master with the *same* `server_id` gets the servers into a messy loop.

What's in one of those relaylogs?

Comment: I am seeing these relay logs on the Master

Comment: I added to my answer.